# How to ignore spaces in string indexes and start with a capital letter on each word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, string, loops

Basically, I have this code, where I want to change a given string to `wEiRd CaSe`, alternate between indexes, for example:

Starting from index **0** I want the letter to be capital, and then when the index got to an odd number, like 1, 3, 5, etc... I want to change it to uppercase.

So:

Stackoverflow should be **StAcKoVeRfLoW**, But I also want to work with strings, strings like this

`This is a test` should be: **ThIs Is A TeSt**

But my function returns : **ThIs iS A TeSt**

Here's my code:

```
"use strict";

var weirdCase = function(string) {
    var characters = string.split("");

    characters.forEach(function(value, index, characters) {
        // If the index is even
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            characters[index] = value.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            characters[index] = value.toLowerCase();
        }
    });

    return characters.join("");
}
```

My question might be a bit misleading, I wanted to be wEiRd Case but also the first letter of the words to be capital, So I did this:

```
function toWeirdCase(string){
  return string.split(' ').map(function(word){
    return word.split('').map(function(letter, index){
      return index % 2 == 0 ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase()
    }).join('');
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Don't use the loop index to decide whether the current letter should be upper or lower case, but keep your own counter - and increase it only if the current character is not a space.

Comment: So should I define a counter variable outside the loop and then check for whitespaces inside the loop and increase it when I found one? and then change the case inside the loop? If you get what I'm saying.

Comment: Please clarify your example: _"This is a test should be: ThIs Is A TeSt"_ - if you just want to ignore spaces, and have every letter alternative between upper and lower case, then the result should actually be `ThIs Is A tEsT`, no?

Comment: @CBroe Actually, I checked, It shouldn't be like that. It should be the way I wrote it,  for multiple words.

Comment: Well, then your question title is misleading. You do not want to ignore spaces, but to start with a capital letter again on each new word.

Comment: Hm... But it includes ignoring whitespaces too.

Comment: It puts the emphasis on the wrong part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another variable `charIndex` which you increase manually only if the value is no space. `charIndex` will represent the indexes for your string like it has no spaces in it.

```
"use strict";

var weirdCase = function(string) {
    var characters = string.split("");
    var charIndex = 0;
    characters.forEach(function(value, index, characters) {
        //Exclude spaces
        if (value === " ") {
            return;
        }

        // If the index is even
        if (charIndex % 2 == 0) {
            characters[index] = value.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            characters[index] = value.toLowerCase();
        }
        //Increment charIndex
        charIndex += 1;
    });

    return characters.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this:

```js
function WeIrDcAsE(string) {
  let isUpperCase = true;
  let result = '';
  for (let character of string) {

    if (isUpperCase) {
      result += character.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += character.toLowerCase();
    }

    if (character.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
      isUpperCase = !isUpperCase;
    } else {
      isUpperCase = true;
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(WeIrDcAsE("This is a test!"));
```

Comment: I like that one. Using a boolean flag is kinda preferable to doing math operations (even if simple) on an index/counter.

Comment: Although, you are throwing away the space characters - and additional else branch to the outer if should add them, `result += ' '`

Answer (score 0):

In a much more simpler way...

```js
a = "This is a test"
b = a.split('')
counter = 0

c = b.map(function(c) {
  if (c === ' ') return c
  if ((counter % 2) === 0) {
    counter++
    return c.toUpperCase()
  }
  counter++
  return c.toLowerCase()
})
console.log(c.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be simplified a lot, I think.

```
var weirdCase = function(str){
    var upper = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] != ' '){
            if (upper){
                str[i] = character.toUpperCase();
            }else{
                str[i] = character.toLowerCase();
            }
            upper = !upper;
     }
}
```

Comment: Disregard this, I just saw Daniel's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows;

```js
var str = "this is a test",
 result = str.split(" ")
             .map(s => [].reduce
                         .call(s, (p,c,i) => p += i & 1 ? c.toLowerCase()
                                                        : c.toUpperCase(),""))
             .join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string= 'Stackoverflow';
for (var i=0; i<string.length; i+=2)
  string= string.substr(0,i) + string[i].toUpperCase() + string.substr(i+1);
```

Nev er mid, scratch this: I need to read more carefully, sorry.